# asp.net and sql events or alerts?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to get an asp.net code (preferably vb.net) to query a sql server for results, but for it to somehow wait for a response from the server when a change is found in the records without resorting to server intensive loops?

For example, I want to write a query which checks the date of a record, if the date is different from last known date, only then should the query return the results.

I am using sql server 2005

Comment: How about checking every X minutes to identify whether a change has happened?

Comment: I need it to be more real-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Service broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043%28SQL.90%29.aspx) call from a trigger?

A connection can't "wait" until something happens and a trigger can't "tell" you soemthing happened

You either have to have a notification from SQL Server or poll the server regularly.

Or have your inserting client tell your web service that something happened etc

Comment: That is what I thought.  I am trying to implement a comet style application, and am having difficulty understanding how to return results from the sql server only when an insert has happened.  In comet style applications, the client creates a connection, then waits with the connection open, and receives the results when the results are available.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a trigger http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

A trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically executes when an event occurs in the database server.

Comment: Is it possible for asp.net to understand when a trigger has been executed?

Comment: Just make sure to remember that a `trigger` runs in the same transaction, so it has the potential to rollback the current transaction.

Comment: I don't think a trigger will work for what I want. I want to write a query which is executed by asp.net which waits for an update or insert in the database, and only then are the results returned to asp.net.